# How do read and display EXIF ImageDescription from all character sets

Tags: php, exif

There are some previous discussions on reading and displaying EXIF ImageDescription and I posted a similar question a few days ago when I began this quest.

This online service reads and displays the exact "Image Description" regardless of character set.

https://exifdata.com/

- So I know it IS possible. I just really wish they explained how they do it.

Despite reading through hours and hours of solutions and help documents on a multitude of sites I have tried over 30 different suggestions but can not get PHP to display the Norwegian ø in the Image Description of this image.

http://www.garryjones.se/testit/1.jpg

Rather than posting 250 rows of my coding for over 30 attempts which looks a mess I am hoping someone knows the answer. It really should be possible with a couple of simple lines of code.

Any help really greatly and humbly received.

Answer (score 0):

I write small code Snippets. I have added an extension is enabled verification. You can try

```
<?php
if (function_exists('exif_read_data')):
try {
    $exif = exif_read_data('');
    foreach ($exif as $property => $value):
        echo "<p>{$property}: ";
        if (is_array($value)) :
            echo "( ";
            foreach ($value as $attribute => $item) {
                echo "{$attribute}:{$item}, ";
            }
            echo " )";
        else :
            echo $value;
        endif;

        echo "</p>";

    endforeach;
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    throw new \Exception($exception->getMessage());
}
else :
    throw new \Exception("EXIF extension is not enabled.");
endif;
?>
```

To know further follow PHP documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).